# Is there a way to save a list using Windows.Storage.ApplicationData with a foreach loop in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am making a UWP app where I want to save the contents of a listbox when the user closes the application. I believe (although I may be wrong) that the best way to do this is by adding the contents of a listbox to a     list    .  However, given the constraints of UWP, I can't use `StreamWriter` to save whatever variables I wish to save, which would allow me to do so easily.  So, I am using     `StorageFolder.GetFileAsync`.

While this is all well and good for saving a few variables, when the amount of variables I would like to save is not predetermined (i.e; a list) I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

```
private async void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = 
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile databaseFile = await 
            storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("database.txt", 
            Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            string databaseItem;
            string databaseName;
            double databaseFat;
            double databaseCarbs;
            double databaseProtein;
            string servingSize;

            txtNameDatabase.Text = txtCaloriesDatabase.Text = txtFatDatabase.Text = txtCarbsDatabase.Text = txtProteinDatabase.Text = txtServingSize.Text = "";
            int databaseCalories;

            ContentDialogResult databaseResult = await databaseContentDialog.ShowAsync();
            bool contentDialogError = false;

            if (databaseResult == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
            {
                try
                {
                    databaseName = txtNameDatabase.Text;
                    databaseCalories = Convert.ToInt32(txtCaloriesDatabase.Text);
                    databaseFat = Convert.ToDouble(txtFatDatabase.Text);
                    databaseCarbs = Convert.ToDouble(txtCarbsDatabase.Text);
                    databaseProtein = Convert.ToDouble(txtProteinDatabase.Text);
                    servingSize = txtServingSize.Text;


                    if (contentDialogError == false)
                    {

                        databaseItem = databaseName + ": " + databaseCalories + " Calories, " + databaseFat + "g Fat, " + databaseCarbs + "g Carbs, " + databaseProtein + "g Protein, Serving Size: " + databaseProtein;
                        foodDatabaseList.Add(databaseItem);
                        lstFoodDatabase.Items.Add(foodDatabaseList[0]);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    var msgContentDialogError = new MessageDialog("Please only enter whole numbers into the calories field and decimal numbers into the macronutrient fields.");
                    await msgContentDialogError.ShowAsync();
                }
                foreach (string line in lstFoodDatabase.Items)
                {
                    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(databaseFile, line);
                }
            }
        }
```

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile databaseFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("database.txt");

            string test = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(databaseFile);
            lstFoodDatabase.Items.Add(test);

        }
```

I tried using a `foreach` loop to save each item in the listbox, but when I try to read it off, I only get the last item that was saved.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to save some structured data, there are usually two ways.
The first one is the `database`, but this method may not be suitable for your situation.
The second is to store the data as serializable text, such as `JSON`.

As you can see from your code, your `foodDatabaseList` is a `List<string>`, we will start here.

Before that, you need to install the **Newtonsoft.Json** nuget package.

```cs
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile databaseFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("database.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

// Data loading

// List serialization
string serialization = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foodDatabaseList);
// Save them
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(databaseFile, serialization);
```

If you need to read them

```cs
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile databaseFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("database.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

string test = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(databaseFile);

List<string> localItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(test);

foreach (var item in localItems)
{
    lstFoodDatabase.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Best regards.